# Unable to check "Allow HTTP traffic" by editing a live Compute Engine Instance in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I need to start a jupyter notebook server on a Google Cloud compute instance and remotely connect to it from my local browser.

The steps laid here in a this blog: 
https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52

mention creating a compute instance with "`Allow HTTP(s) traffic`". I already have an existing instance on which I wish to start the server, so I am trying to edit it. But as soon as I check these two boxes and click save, it reverts back to unchecked and grayed out boxes. And of course I am unable to connect to the Jupyter I launched from the instance.

Does one need to stop a compute engine and only then will be able to edit this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Go to VPC network -> Firewall rules.
3. Look for two rules `default-allow-http` and `default-allow-https`.
   If these rules are missing you will need to recreate them.
4. Go to Compute Engine -> VM instances.
5. Click on your instance.
6. Look for two Network tags `http-server` and `https-server`. If they
   are missing add these tags.

Comment: I realized I was using a different port than what I had created in Firewall Rules. Just fixing that fixed my problem.